# MongoDB console: Getting the _id of a cursor object

Tags: mongodb, cursor

Is it possible to get the _id of a cursor? The following method does not work for me.

```
> var cursor = db.genre.find({name:"romance"})
> db.genre.find({name:"romance"}, {"_id":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c03537d7d0db45bee0f64d0") } // output
```

I just would like the value: ObjectId("5c03537d7d0db45bee0f64d0" to be returned.

Comment: Did you try `db.genre.find({name:"romance"}, {"_id":1})[0]._id` ?

Comment: This works. Thank you.

Comment: If you only want to return the value from a single document, you could use `findOne()` instead of `find()`. I think this query looks more straightforward: `db.genre.findOne({name:"romance"},{_id:1})._id`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mickl, the answer is

db.genre.find({name:"romance"}, {"_id":1})[0]._id